# How can I automatically download multiple sites through Coda?

Tags: applescript, automator, data-transfer, script, coda

I have several sites in Coda that I would like to automatically re-download when I tell it to. The sites are collaboratively managed, and I'd like to download a fresh copy of the sites automatically. I am open to AppleScripting, an Automator workflow, a shell script, a combination of all three, or anything else you suggest. How would I go about doing this?

Edit: Can I write a shell script to download the whole site via FTP, then copy it to my "Sites" folder and overwrite the existing data? I need to be able to do it for more than one site, so I need a way to pass in the domain name, user, password, and the directory I want it to copy to.

Comment: Would there happen to be a source-control system (CVS, SVN, Git, Mercurial) helping along this "collaboratively managed" website?

Comment: @VxJasonxV No, it's a custom framework.

Comment: Good question @VxJasonxV. If you did use SVN, for example, updates would e easy, plus you get the benefit of not having your collaborators randomly overwriting your updates. It's the way to go!

Comment: @Anthony I really just want to write an Applescript/shell script to do it. I know it can be done, I just don't have the scripting knowledge to know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could easily use wget for this and script it any which way you like. Here's a quick example of how you could use it to download and overwrite one of your sites in one line:

```
wget ~/Sites/domain/ ftp://[username]:[password]@ftp.example.com/www/
```

So to do multiple websites you would use:

```
wget -P ~/Sites/ -i sites.txt
```

And your text file might look something like this:

```
ftp://username:password@ftp.site1.com/www/
ftp://username:password@ftp.site2.com/www/
ftp://username:password@ftp.site3.com/www/
```

From the wget man page:

```
Recursive download:
  -r,  --recursive          specify recursive download.
  -l,  --level=NUMBER       maximum recursion depth (inf or 0 for infinite).
       --delete-after       delete files locally after downloading them.
  -k,  --convert-links      make links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to
                            local files.
  -K,  --backup-converted   before converting file X, back up as X.orig.
  -m,  --mirror             shortcut for -N -r -l inf --no-remove-listing.
  -p,  --page-requisites    get all images, etc. needed to display HTML page.
       --strict-comments    turn on strict (SGML) handling of HTML comments.

Recursive accept/reject:
  -A,  --accept=LIST               comma-separated list of accepted extensions.
  -R,  --reject=LIST               comma-separated list of rejected extensions.
  -D,  --domains=LIST              comma-separated list of accepted domains.
       --exclude-domains=LIST      comma-separated list of rejected domains.
       --follow-ftp                follow FTP links from HTML documents.
       --follow-tags=LIST          comma-separated list of followed HTML tags.
       --ignore-tags=LIST          comma-separated list of ignored HTML tags.
  -H,  --span-hosts                go to foreign hosts when recursive.
  -L,  --relative                  follow relative links only.
  -I,  --include-directories=LIST  list of allowed directories.
  --trust-server-names             use the name specified by the redirection
                                   url last component.
  -X,  --exclude-directories=LIST  list of excluded directories.
  -np, --no-parent                 don't ascend to the parent directory.
```

Comment: Cool! How could I pass in domains, the ~/Sites/domain, users, and passwords?

Comment: You can create a text file that handles all of them. (updated answer)

Comment: I don't have time right now to test this, but when I do, I'll let you know. Thanks so much!

Comment: sure. it's very simple to do what you're wanting; any changes to the syntax would be minor.

Comment: It's only downloading index.html. How do I download all of the folders and the files in them?

Comment: put and -r in the arguments to recursively retrieve files; you can also use -l 1 to go down one level for instance. [wget / Recursive Retrieval Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html)

Comment: Awesome! I will try it when I get a chance. Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries; let me know if you have anymore questions - I'm happy to help.

Comment: I do have one more question (I hope it's only one). How do I download only certain folders/files? It's downloading _everything_ including log files and other invisible files.

Comment: @daviesgeek, when you said 'Can I write a shell script to download the whole site' I assumed you wanted all of it. Do you want just specific files, or specific folders? You can drill down into more specific directories by specifying them after the `/www/` like `/www/path/to/file/`. Is that what you mean? I've included some `wget` arguments into my original answer that should help.